# Не могу передать данные с одной переменной в другую

Tags: c#, xml, парсер, конвертер

Конвертер валют считывает данные с сайта Нац. Банка, но не могу значение USD, EUR, RUB курса валюты  передать к каждой необходимой переменной, чтобы оно работало именно этими валютами, после присвоить эти курсы в следующие конструкцию switch, он почему-то не видит эти переменные. В программировании новичок и многого не понимаю.
 Пока имею такой код:

```
class valet
{
    public string r030 { get; set; }
    public string txt { get; set; }
    public string rateStr { get; set; }
    public string cc { get; set; }
    public decimal rate { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static decimal RoundUp(decimal number, int digits)
    {
        var factor = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, digits));
        return Math.Ceiling(number * factor) / factor;
    }
 static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange");
        XmlElement xRoot = doc.DocumentElement;
        List<valet> List = new List<valet>();
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("currency"))
        {
            valet valet = new valet();
            foreach (XmlNode childnode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (childnode.Name == "rate")
                    valet.rateStr = childnode.InnerText;
                if (childnode.Name == "cc")
                    valet.cc = childnode.InnerText;
                if (childnode.Name == "txt")
                    valet.txt = childnode.InnerText;
                if (childnode.Name == "r030")
                    valet.r030 = childnode.InnerText;
            }
            List.Add(valet);
        }

        decimal tempEUR, tempUSD, tempRUB;
        foreach (var el in List)
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(el.rateStr, out tempEUR))
            {
                el.rate = tempEUR;
                Console.WriteLine(el.rateStr);
            }

            if (decimal.TryParse(el.rateStr, out tempUSD))
            {
                el.rate = tempUSD;
                Console.WriteLine(el.rateStr);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(el.rateStr);
            if (decimal.TryParse(el.rateStr, out tempRUB))
            {
                el.rate = tempRUB;
                Console.WriteLine(el.rateStr);
            }
        }
decimal UAH;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите сумму, необходимую перевести в UAN, USD, EUR...");
                UAH = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Выберите операцию перевода: 'RUB' 'USD' 'EUR'");

            string action = Console.ReadLine();

            valet v = GetValetByCurrency(action, List);
            if (v != null)
            {
                switch (action)
                {
                    case "RUB":
                        Console.WriteLine(UAH + " UAH = " + RoundUp(UAH * 1, 2) + " RUB");
                        break;

                    case "USD":
                        Console.WriteLine(UAH + " UAH = " + RoundUp(UAH * 1, 2) + " USD");
                        break;

                    case "EUR":
                        Console.WriteLine(UAH + " UAH = " + RoundUp(UAH * 1, 2) + " EUR");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Не удалось распознать операцию! Нажмите Enter для продолжения...");
                        break;
                }
            }

            static valet GetValetByCurrency(string currency, List<valet> valets)


            {
                foreach (valet v in valets)
                {
                    if (v.cc == currency)
                        return v;
                }
                return null;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

```
class valet { 
  public string r030 { get; set; }
  public string txt { get; set; }
  public string rateStr { get; set; }
  public string cc { get; set; }
  public decimal rate { get; set; }
}
```

2.

```
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("currency"))
        {
            valet valet = new valet();
            foreach (XmlNode childnode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
              if (childnode.Name == "rate")
                    valet.rateStr = childnode.InnerText;
              if (childnode.Name == "cc")
                    valet.cc = childnode.InnerText;
              if (childnode.Name == "txt")
                    valet.txt = childnode.InnerText;
              if (childnode.Name == "r030")
                    valet.r030 = childnode.InnerText;
            }
            List.Add(valet);
        }
```

3.

```
        decimal temp;
        foreach (var el in List)
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(el.rateStr, out temp))
                 el.rate = temp;
            Console.WriteLine(el.cc, el.rateStr, el.rate);
        }
```

4.

```
             Console.WriteLine("Выберите операцию перевода: 'RUB' 'USD' 'EUR'");
             string action = Console.ReadLine();
             valet v = GetValetByCurrency(action, List);
             if (v != null)
             {
                  Console.WriteLine(UAH + " UAH = " + RoundUp(UAH * v.rate, 2) + " RUB");
             }
```

5.

```
static valet GetValetByCurrency(string currency, List<valet> valets)
{
    foreach (valet v in valets)
    {
        if (v.cc == currency)
            return v;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Не могу переменную temp присвоить в цикл switсh для продолжения работы программы по смыслу. Она приватная получается. Как можно это обойти дело? За ранее благодарен.

Comment: @ЗаирМеметов Посмотрите изменения. Не знаю, правильно ли я Вас понял.

Comment: Очень благодарен за помощь, но основная проблема так и не решена.
В первую очередь el.rate = temp; - не удается неявно преобразовать тип "decimal" в "string". 
И данные курса валюты одной переменной не передаются в другую дальше по продолжению программы. Я делаю через switch

Comment: @ЗаирМеметов Обратите внимание на `public decimal rate { get; set; }` в начале ответа.

Comment: Я обновил код, постарался описать понятно, уже четвертый день убиваюсь и ничего не могу сделать с ним... Элементарно не хватает знаний, экзамен через 2 дня, надо доделать программу как-то... За ранее благодарен.